# use res.render() instead of res.send() in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ckeditor

I have programmed the image uploader for ckeditor. Each time a file is uploaded, an html file containing the name of the image has to be sent back to the client.

Here's my code:

```
router.post('/upload', function (req, res, next) {
var imageName = req.files.upload.name;

var html = "<script type='text/javascript'>" +
            "var funcNum = " + req.query.CKEditorFuncNum + "; " +
            "var url = \"/images/" + imageName + "\";" +
            "window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(funcNum, url);" +
            "</script>";

res.send(html);
});
```

This is a very dirty solution, so I have created the following .hjs file and mapped values correspondingly:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var funcNum = {{funcNum}};
  var url = "/images/" + {{imageName}};
  window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(funcNum, url);
</script>
```

And my server-side:

```
router.post('/upload', function (req, res, next) {
  var imageName = req.files.upload.name;
  res.render('ckeditor-response', {funcNum: req.query.CKEditorFuncNum, imageName: imageName});
});
```

This generates exactly the same html file as the hardcoded solution above, however it does not work for ckeditor. Is there any significant difference between these two solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure about `[...]This generates exactly the same html file[...]`? You should always check the final result, e.g. in the network tab of the browsers developer-tools.

If `imageName`  is `test.jpg`  your first code creates

```
var url = "/images/test.jpg";
```

But your `hjs` will create:

```
 var url = "/images/" + test.jpg;
```

which is a syntax error. You are looking for `"/images/{{imageName}}";`

Beside that you should write the response that way:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function() {
   var funcNum = {{funcNum}};
   var url = "/images/{{imageName}}";
   window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(funcNum, url);
}());
</script>
```

**OR**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction({{funcNum}}, "/images/{{imageName}}");
</script>
```

Otherwise you will *pollute* the global namespace of the editor window with `funcNum`  and `url`.

Comment: Thank you niese! My stupid mistake was on `var url = "/images/" + {{imageName}};`